# Conditional Sum SQL

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I am very new to SQL and have been presented with, what seems to me, a complex task. I have a table which is generating the number of various fruit purchased on a given day. Thus:

```
                  G. A G.B  
2016-06-01  Banana  45  0       
2016-06-01  Pear    158 0   
2016-06-01  apple   0   23
 .... dates continue
```

I need to develop some kind of conditional  sum to count how many types of fruit are bought with a specific grade on a specific date.  So in the above case on the given date (2016-06-01) there would be 203 Grade A (G.A) bits of fruit and 23 Grade B (G.B) pieces of fruit.

Naturally some kind of

```
  Sum(case when date=date then Grade else 0 ).
```

But, I am really baffled here. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Can you post a sample expected result set. Also, specify which database you are using.  And no, I don't think a conditional sum is required.  Simple aggregate functions should do the trick.

Comment: Move the DATE condition to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple group clause should do the job here (Note: untested code)

```
select date, sum(grade_a) as grade_a_sum, sum(grade_b) as grade_b_sum
from sales
group by date;
```

This will give the grades for every date. Individual dates can then be selected if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Won't simple group by do the work..

```
Select 
date,
sum(GA) as GA,
sum(GB) as GB
from
Table
group by date
```